# SSH to a remote computer having only the public IP

Tags: ssh, ip

Is it possible to connect to a computer behind a router via SSH knowing only the public IP address (of the router)?

Comment: What happens if you do `ssh <IP>` ?

Comment: do you have windows? then you may need putty

Comment: It seems to load indefinitely.
I'm on Debian by the way.

Comment: Try `ssh -v <IP>` and paste it on a pastebin like http://pastebin.com or in your post.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dDxd4GjQ
Here it is. Edit: It then times out.

Answer (score 7):

**Are you the administrator of the remote machine/network?**

**Yes.** You need to forward port 22 (or whichever port you're running ssh on) through your firewall. In addition, I suggest doing a few things to make hacking more difficult, such as switching to a different port, allowing public key only, or limiting remote connections to certain IP addresses.

Alternatively, you need to set up a VPN to get you through the remote firewall.

Alternatively, you may need to first ssh to the remote firewall, then the remote machine from there.

If you're only the administrator of that machine, not of the network, you need to ask the network administrator.

**No.** You need to ask the administrator of the remote machine/network how to access it, and if he/she doesn't know, suggest he/she set up one of the above.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your ssh output http://pastebin.com/dDxd4GjQ it seems like ssh isn't open on default port 22 on the remote host. (possibly no ssh at all, or a firewall is protecting it).

If you have authorisation, you can scan the ports of this host to see if there's a binding ssh port on another port.

Something like :

```
nmap -sS <IP>
```

Comment: Isn't the host a router ? I mean, the public IP leads to the router that then leads the connection via the private network IP to the computer ?

Comment: @Zack Dibe - You should edit your question to provide some more information about what you are trying to connect to. If it's a machine behind a router, then that's a different problem from connecting directly.